# How to load and bind texture in OpenGL ES?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

So, I have a texture in my res/drawable-hdpi (text.png, for example) folder, how I can load this texture and bind it with glBindTexture?

Comment: I've try to load it with R class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.text);
int[] texId = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texId, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId[0]);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, img, 0);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
```

1. Decode resource to bitmap
2. Generate texture
3. Bind Texture
4. Upload texture
5. Set minification filter for completeness